# Ruby from-to-step Sequence

Tags: ruby

```
def generator(from, to, step)
  ary = [from]
  nex = from += step
  min = from += step
  while from != to 
     if from < to 
       from += step 
        ary.push(nex)
        nex += step
     elsif from > to
        from -= step
        ary.push(min)
        min -= step
     else           
        return nil 
     end   
 end
 return ary
end
```

can Someone help explain to me why this only returns up to the 'to'element minus 2

for example when 
generator(10,20,1) it will return [10,11,12..18] instead of going all the way to 20

Comment: Indentation is very important to understanding your code, especially when there's a lot going on like you have here. Try to keep it neat and orderly when asking for help.

Comment: Can you not use `(from..to).step(step).to_a`?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
nex = from += step
min = from += step
```

To

```
nex = from + step
min = from + step
```

Your `from` is already being incremented twice with the step because of that (so it loops less than intended).

If you want to write it in a one-liner you could do something like this using [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step)

```
2.3.0 > 10.step(20).to_a
#=> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

2.3.0 > 20.step(10, -1).to_a
#=> [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]
```

Comment: Hmm. Thank you. Your solution works well for that specific example I gave. But it does not work when the the from is a higher number than the to. It leaves me with a blank array.

Comment: There's some flaw in the logic of your code, if you change to ``ary.push(from)`` instead of ``nex`` and ``min`` then you should see your expected behavior ``generator(20,10,1)`` should result in a reverse. I do have to mention that  if you provide a step that skips over your ``to`` number then you're going to end up in an infinite loop.